# When a security update is applied as a patch, does the product name change?

Tags: security, patch

When a security update is applied as a patch, does the product name change?

I.e. Windows Server 2008

If this server undergoes a patch and/or security update, does it still appear as Windows Server 2008, or does it have to undergo a name change -

I.e Windows Server 2008 version 2, or Windows Server 2008 R2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the installed OS name will not change as the result of a patch.  Only an OS upgrade/reinstall does that (and service packs change the service pack level).

Comment: Great, thanks Andrew - really helpful.  Just out of interest, do you know if Microsoft Windows has stopped developing patches/updates for older versions of software? Or does it continuously develop patches for all software versions?

Comment: Basically what I am wondering is whether there is any point in upgrading from Microsoft Server 2008 with the latest service packs, to Microsoft Server 2012 purely for the added security.

Comment: You can look up support cycle dates for the various Windows Server releases here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search?sort=PN&alpha=Windows%20Server&Filter=FilterNO. They do eventually stop releasing patches for older operating systems.